Domain Truncation Error for Semi-Infinite BVP
Suppose I have a BVP defined on a semi-infinite domain, of a form that looks something like $$ N[f] = 0 \\ f(0) = a \\f'(0) =b \\ f'(\infty) = c$$ where $f$ is some (generically nonlinear) third order differential operator. It is common to solve such a BVP by performing a domain truncation of length $L$, and solving the related BVP $$ N[f] = 0 \\ f(0) = a \\f'(0) =b \\ f'(L) = c.$$ Of course, there's a lot of theory that describes how different a numerical solution (say, some Runge-Kutta method with shooting) of the second system will look compared to the second system. But I would like to know if there's some theory that can give something like an asymptotic analysis of the error incurred by the domain truncation itself. That is, if $f_\infty$ is the (non-numerical) solution to the first system, and $f_L$ the solution to the second, what, if anything, is known about the decay rate of $$ \max_{x \in [0, L]} |f_\infty(x) - f_L(x)| $$ as $L \to \infty$?
If it is relevant, my curiosity stems from the Blasius boundary layer, where $N[f]=2f''' + ff''$ and $a=b=0$ and $c=1$, but it would be nice to know what, if anything, can be done in a reasonably general setting.
I did try and work out an example in the case the $N$ is linear and constant-coefficient, and there it seems one can get a reasonable answer because the solution space is quite simple, and the coefficients of the solutions are changing. It's possible the linearization about $\infty$ could therefore yield some kind of progress, but it's not clear because one also needs to apply the boundary conditions back at $0$ where that isn't valid.
